# Convert a str into pyspark.sql.types.StructType

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I have given a .csv file by business which has filed details of MATERIAL_MASTER fileds.

[image: | | Another header | | -------- | -------------- | | First | row | | Second | row |]

in Databricks i have created one notebook where i am reading this file and creating the Schema out of it.

```
import pandas as pd
rows=[]
material_master_schema_df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/dentanalyticsdatalake/main-data/POC/RAW/MaterialMasterSchema.csv",header = True)
material_master_schema_df= material_master_schema_df.toPandas()
rows = material_master_schema_df.values.tolist()
#print(rows)

var= [ 'StructField'+str(tuple(i)) for i in rows]
#print(var)

fields = []
for i in var:
    fields.append(str(str(i.split(',')[0])+','+(i.split(',')[1].split("'")[1]+'Type()'+','+(i.split(',')[2].split("'")[1]+')'))))
    
#print(fields) 

Current_Schema = 'StructType'+'('+str(fields)+')'
material_master_schema = Current_Schema.replace('"','')
```

Now what i am trying is to in another notebook i am calling this notebook and trying to use this schema while creating a DataFrame.

```
%run ./Schema_Creation_Notebook

MATERIAL_MASTER_TXT_DF = spark.read.csv("/xxx/file.txt",header = True, sep='\t',schema = material_master_schema )
```

But this is throwing me "ParseException Error" and i noticed the type(material_master_schema) is str not StructType.

Can someone help me to understand is this approach is feasible anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The `material_master_schema` has the correct StructType syntax but as a string. So, we can use `eval()` function to solve the issue. `eval()` functions takes a string expression as an argument and evaluates it as a normal python code. So, assign `eval(material_master_schema)` value to `schema` while reading csv using `spark.read.csv()`.

- Value of material_master_schema (String) after executing Schema_Creation_Notebook:

```
StructType([StructField('MATERIAL_MASTER_SURROGATE_KEY',StringType(),True), StructField('MATERIAL_NUMBER',StringType(),True), StructField('MATERIAL_FAMILY',StringType(),True)])
```

- Revised code using `eval()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType

df = spark.read.csv("/xxx/file.txt", header=True, sep='\t', schema=eval(material_master_schema))
```

- Schema of output dataframe:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- MATERIAL_MASTER_SURROGATE_KEY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MATERIAL_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MATERIAL_FAMILY: string (nullable = true)
```